# Laptop doesn't connect to internet while other computers are connected

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Having problems connecting wirelessly a laptop to home internet router. Other computers see the network just fine, but when this one is attempting to connect it fails and the whole network goes down, so that I have to reset the router to get it back on other computers.

The laptop is on Windows 7, one of the other computers runs windows7 as well and is working.

It does connect on cable though.

What might be a problem and what steps should I take to eliminate it?

Comment: Check there is not a duplicate IP address configured in the wireless settings for this device in the router.

Answer (score 0):

I would have asked to check if the network card is corrupted, but router crashing doesn't make sense to me.

try this.

disable the wireless connection from network connection and remove it. then reboot the system. let the OS determine the hardware and install it. Then check for any software updates for the hardware and install them.

that should fix the issue logically.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided guidance on how the user acomplishes each of the things you suggested. It isn't clear by the question if the user knows how to do those things or not.